# Tablespace creation inside testcontainers

Tags: flyway, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I am working to setup a test for our SpringBoot Repositories. We are using Postgres database.

I chose to use testcontainers. Besides this it was required to use flyway because our Postrgress schema creation script is quite complex and the script execution by @DataJpaTest wasn't manage to interpreted.

We are using tablespaces within the schema creation sql files. I am struggling to setup the postgres database within the testcontainer to have this kind of tablespaces.

First I created the folders inside the testcontainers:

```
@Container
private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:14-alpine").withDatabaseName("test_db");

@BeforeAll
static void initContainer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    postgres.execInContainer("mkdir", "/tsd01");
    postgres.execInContainer("chown", "-R", "postgres.postgres", "/tsd01/");
    postgres.execInContainer("mkdir", "/tsi01");
    postgres.execInContainer("chown", "-R", "postgres.postgres", "/tsi01/");
}
```

After this I added in the sql scripts that are executed by FlyWay the tablespace creation commands:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE customschema_indexes LOCATION '/tsd01';
CREATE TABLESPACE customschema_tables LOCATION '/tsi01';
```

The Flyway throws an exception:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Detected both transactional and non-transactional statements within the same migration (even though mixed is false). Offending statement found at line 23: CREATE TABLESPACE customschema_indexes LOCATION '/tsd01' [non-transactional]
```

Does anybody has any idea how I can create the tablespace in my setup?

Comment: I hope this can help https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2801#issuecomment-623534302